# Is this a correct statement of the probability chain rule?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Everywhere I see the chain rule written in this order:
$$
\Pr (A,B,C) = \Pr (A|B,C) \Pr (B|C) \Pr (C).
$$
Is this the same as
$$
\Pr (A) \Pr (B|A) \Pr (C|B,A),
$$
where the conditioning is done with different variables?

Comment: With the roles of $A$ and $C$ interchanged, they're the same, and they result from applying the same rule, but the expressions are plainly different.

Comment: "Plainly different" as in the text?  Don't they have the same value?  From the answer  below it seems yes.

Comment: A and C don't have the same value. If you mean 'don't the entire expressions have the same value' then trivially they do, since they derive from decomposing the same event (ABC) in two different ways (which is nothing more than exploiting the symmetry of symbols in ABC -- the event ABC is the event CBA), but that doesn't make the expressions themselves "the same" -- because what is conditioned on in each expression is different. If you intended to only refer to the same value, you could edit your wording to more clearly reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're the same.

Set intersections are commutative, so:
$$A\cap B\cap C = C \cap B \cap A$$
And you already know that:
$$
P(ABC) = P(A|BC)*P(B|C)*P(C)
$$
So:
$$
\begin{align}
P(A|BC)*P(B|C)*P(C) & = P(ABC)\\
& = P(CBA)\\
& = P(C|BA)*P(B|A)*P(A)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much.  Thats a great concise answer and makes total sense.

Comment: Glad I could help!